# I can't install widyr in R to calculate network of words. Are there any alternatives?

Tags: r, text-mining

I would like to use the widyr function to count the number of times words occur together and to examine correlations between words in text mining of reviews. When installing the widyr package, R keeps giving a warning message "package ‘widyr’ is not available (for R version 3.4.0)".

I'm wondering if there is a substitute for widyr, as changing R versions will render some packages invalid or is there a way for me to install widyr?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The warning message is because `widyr` is not available from CRAN. You need to install it from [Github](https://github.com/dgrtwo/widyr) using `devtools`.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("dgrtwo/widyr")
```